# Please explain the part of this delegate syntax: "<T>"

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I asked a related question a few weeks ago, but this particular detail was not addressed.

In this delegate:

```
public delegate T LoadObject<T>(SqlDataReader dataReader);
```

I understand that the first T is the user-declared return object, and that the entire delegate deals with a method that takes a SqlDataReader, but what does the `<T>` mean?

Comment: If I correctly recall, T in this case is template (or basically it can be used for one of several types).

Comment: It means that delegate is `generic`. You can use any type instead of it: `MyObject obj = LoadObject<MyObject>(myDataReader);`. More:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Dot Net Generics, working with generic delegates should not be an issue.
As mentioned by @pwas, please refer to MSDN generic documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

To clear your doubt, you can bind your delegate with only those methods who have the same Type as of initialized delegate reference:

Example-

```
        public delegate T LoadObject<T>(SqlDataReader dataReader);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadObject<int> del = Test1; //Valid
            LoadObject<string> del1 = Test1; //Compile Error
        }

        public static int Test1(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            return 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# we have generic classes, generic methods, and generic delegates, generic Interfaces and generic Structs. consider the example below:

```
public delegate T MaxDelegate<T>(T a, T b);
void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine(  MaxClass<int>.whatIsTheMax(2,3) );

    // Just as a class when using a generic method,You must tell the compiler
    // the type parameter
    Console.WriteLine( MaxMethod<int>(2,3) );

    // Now the max delegate of type MaxDelegate will only accept a method that has
    //   int someMethod(int a, int b) .It has the benefit of compile time check
    MaxDelegate<int>  m = MaxMethod<int>;

    // MaxDelegate<int> m2 = MaxMethod<float>; // compile time check and error



    m(2,3);
   //m(2.0,3.0);  //compile time check and error
}

public static T MaxMethod<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
{
   T retval = a;
   if(a.CompareTo(b) < 0)
     retval = b;
   return retval;
}

public class MaxClass<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public static  T whatIsTheMax(T a, T b)
   {
       T retval = a;
        if ( a.CompareTo(b) < 0)
            retval = b;
        return retval;
    }
}
```